# Published extension doesn't work like in development

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently trying to develop an extension for VSCode.

In development it works fine.
However on another PC which downloads from the marketplace my extension doesn't work.

The error `Running the contributed command:'dynamicsnav.compile_obj' failed.` pops up on every command run.

Is it possible to debug my extension on another machine which downloads my extension?

[Sourcecode of extension](https://github.com/CloudReadySoftware/DynamicsNAVSCM)

[Vscode marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cloudreadysoftware.dynamics-nav-scm)

Comment: Sounds like maybe you are not including a file that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the full debugging abilities but since vscode (and Electron on which vscode is based) is essentially a browser you can use the developer tools (Help -> Developer Tools) to see error messages.

Comment: I can open the developer tools in VSCode, but the only stacktrace I have access to is the errorhandling of the in the mainwindow. I don't see how I can debug why my extension is failing.

Comment: I know it's limited, but at least you can see error messages to find things that made a script fail to load.